# List process details

Tags: linux, process, ps

How can I list process details for a specific process?

I know about commands like `ps -ef` but they all truncate the details to fit into fixed column widths. For example, in one listing I can see that the username is truncated.

Is there a command that lists the full, uncut, details of a specified process, one detail per line?

Comment: Have you try `ps -efl` and redirect to file? And then open the file.

Comment: Yes, `ps -efl >file` still uses fixed-width columns and truncates the details.

Comment: What about `ps auxxx`?

Comment: Just pipe it through `cat`, as in `ps -ef | cat`.

Comment: @Bib, it still truncates the username due to the fixed width of the USER column.

Comment: It shouldn't, it really shouldn't. You have something going on. Perhaps `ps` is a script, or at least not the original version.

Comment: @Bib my `ps` is the standard one that comes from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS: `ps --version` says "ps from procps-ng 3.3.17". The first line of `ps -ef | cat` shows the header as `UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD`. Note the width of UID, which is not big enough to show usernames unambiguously. What kind of output do you get and what version of ps are you using?